# How to display different checkbox name based on current time?

Tags: javascript, html, function, checkbox, time

I'm building an app to remind people to take medication, the app will display the medication(s) the user should take based on the current time, e.g if the user need to take medication 1 and 2 at 10am, then when the time is 10am-10:59am, the checkboxes will display "medication 1" and "medication 2" for the user to tick off. But if the user need to take medication 3 and 4 at 9pm, then at 9pm-9:59pm, the checkboxes will display "medication 3" and "medication 4".

The html I currently have:

```
               <div id=aa style="display:none">
        <form>
            <input type="checkbox" name="Medication 1" value="one">Supplement One<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="Medication 2" value="two">Supplement Two<br>
            <input id=xbutton type="button" onClick="validate()" value="Submit">
        </form>

    </div>
```

Right now as you can see the app will display just Medication 1 and Medication 2 no matter what time the user open the app. Is there a way to make the checkboxes display different words based on the current time?

Comment: Could you include your JavaScript code?!

Comment: I don't have javascript code for this function as I'm not sure how to do it. The validate() function is just to verify if all checkboxes are checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just the design. It can be done through several ways, one of which is below:

Use JavaScript to get current time

```
var dt = new Date();
var time = dt.getHours();
```

Can also be done by jQuery( much cleaner)

You can include all the check boxes initially in your HTML but set their `display: none;`

Now you can setup js to work accordingly, as:

```
If(time > 9 && time < 10) //9am-10am
{
    $('#medication1').css('display','block');
    $('#medication2').css('display','block');
}
```

Just like this you can set js for other time periods. **Make sure to set** `display: none;` for all medication check boxes before setting specific check boxes `display: block;` This would clear check boxes which were set visible before.

Comment: Thanks for this! Never thought about doing it this way! :)